# symfony3: create form for entity that has a column with many to one relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony

I have a "Tasks" table that references a "Estados" table with a foreign key from column Tasks.taskestado to Estados.estado.

Here's the relevant XML mapping for Tasks:

```
<entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Tasks" table="TASKS" repository-class="AppBundle\Repository\TasksRepository">
<id name="taskid" type="bigint" column="TaskID">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
...
<many-to-one field="taskestado" target-entity="Estados" fetch="LAZY">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="TaskEstado" referenced-column-name="Estado"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
...
```

And for Estados:

```
<entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Estados" table="ESTADOS">
<id name="estado" type="string" column="Estado" length="15">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="estadodescricao" type="string" column="EstadoDescricao" length="50" nullable="true">
  <options>
    <option name="fixed"/>
  </options>
</field>
...
```

Given this, I'm trying to make an action (novaAction()) to create tasks.
Here's the Controller code:

```
public function novaAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Tasks();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    dump($task);
    #$task->setTaskEstado(new Estados());
    $form = $this->createForm(TasksType::class, $task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Criar a tarefa na BD
            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'app.nova_tarefa.mensagem_sucesso');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('nova_tarefa');
        }

        $this->addFlash('error', 'app.nova_tarefa.mensagem_erro');
    }
```

And the relevant TasksType code:

```
class TasksType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('taskid', HiddenType::class)
        ...
        #->add('taskestado')
        ->add('taskestado', EntityType::class, [ 'class' => 'AppBundle:Estados' ])
        ...
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tasks',
        #'empty_data' => function (\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form) {
        #    #return new Tasks($form->get('tasks')->getData());
        #    return new Tasks();
        #},
    ));
}
}
```

The 'empty_data' option was an attempt to create the form without passing an instance of Tasks to it.
Also, I have the same result when I add taskestado with the commented code, i. e., without arguments.

And here's the relevant Tasks entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Tasks
 */
class Tasks
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $taskid;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Estados
     */
    protected $taskestado;

    ...

    /**
     * Get taskid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getTaskid()
    {
        return $this->taskid;
    }

    /**
     * Set taskestado
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Estados $taskestado
     *
     * @return Tasks
     */
    public function setTaskestado(\AppBundle\Entity\Estados $taskestado = null)
    {
        $this->taskestado = $taskestado;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get taskestado
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Estados
     */
    public function getTaskestado()
    {
        return $this->taskestado;
    }

    ...
}
```

When I open the page, I get the following error:

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

I'd also generated the CRUD (`bin/console doctrine:generate:crud --filter=Tasks`), so that I could check how it's done, but the code is similar, as well as the results (after fixing some issues in the TasksType for some datetime columns).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have code in your  `Task` entity that automatically initialises the `taskestado` with something?

Comment: Before I add the mblaettermann's code, I even didn't had the __construct() function.

Comment: Can you show the code of that entity class nonetheless?

Comment: Yes, I've added the relevant part.

The XML mapping was initially generated by doctrine, as well as the entities.

Comment: And you always get the error no matter if you remove `$task->setTaskEstado(new Estados())` or keep it?

Comment: Yes. Even if using a fetched object (as per findOneBy(...)), as I'm trying now, I get the same result.

Comment: Are you able to push the project somewhere or to fork the Symfony Standard Edition and make the necessary changes to reproduce your problem?

Comment: As this is an internal project, and it has some more features, not I'm not able to do so. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer to this, it was far from obvious.

As I've said in the question, there's a many-to-one relationship from Tasks.taskestado to Estados.estado. Estados.estado is a string, that can be nullable, an empty string or (normally) a non-empty string. Although not indicated in the mapping, the empty string is the default value for taskestado.

I already have data on the table, and one of the entries for Estados.estado is precisely the empty string.

I didn't post in the question, but I saw the following information in the stack trace of this exception:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\RuntimeException: Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
    at n/a
        in /var/www/simpletask2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/IdReader.php line 119

    at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\IdReader->getIdValue(object(Estados))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), object(Estados))
        in /var/www/simpletask2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php line 204

    at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList->flatten(array(object(Estados), object(Estados), object(Estados), object(Estados), object(Estados), object(Estados), object(Estados), object(Estados)), array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), array(), array(), array())
        in /var/www/simpletask2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php line 91
```

So, the EntityType retrieved the values from the database and was trying to render them. In other words, they were already persisted and the problem could not really reside in how I initialized the entity.

So, I remembered about the empty string value for the Estados entity, and tried to remove it from the database: problem solved, the TaskEstado entity was initialized and rendered as expected.

Now I need a way to work around this, but the solution was found.

Thank all for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you need to set cascade = persist in your mappings for Tasks. For example:

```
<many-to-one field="taskestado" target-entity="Estados" fetch="LAZY">
  <cascade>
     <cascade-persist/>
  </cascade>
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="TaskEstado" referenced-column-name="Estado"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
```

Also Instead of doing `$em->persist($form->getData());`
Use `$em->persist($task);`

See if that works...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the you have

```
$this->taskestado = new ArrayCollection();
```

in the `__construct()` of your `Tasks` class.

Then 2 notices:

Try to only use english in your code. This way you get much more responses.
As a "best practise" use Singulars for your entity class names Like `Task`, `TaskEstado`

Comment: Thank you or your answer.
Unfortunately, it didn't work, and I still have the exact same issue. As per symfony suggestion, I used ArrayCollection from the namespace "Doctrine\Common\Collections\".

The english part is my fault, even if the original code isn't in english.
About the singular/plural, that's more difficult, as that's not how the table was built, several years ago. I have little to no control of the table names.

Comment: Also, this is a ManyToOne relationship. From what I know, it seems that your solution is only valid for a OneToMany relationship.

Comment: You may control table namens used in SQL seperatly with @Table Annotation

Comment: are you sure that initializing with `$this->taskestado = new ArrayCollection();` is appropriate for a many-to-one? Isn't it for One-To-Many relationships?

Comment: Having English terms would make it easier :-) for the other relation dirction uae collection Form type instead of entity

Comment: I don't have the other relation direction, as I don't use it.